# Is Haskell designed to encourage Hungarian Notation?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell and started noticing common suffixes in functions like:

```
debugM
mapM_
mapCE
```

Which is known as Hungarian Notation. But at the same time I can use type classes to write non-ambiguous code like:

```
show
return
```

Since functions like `map` are so common and used in many contexts, why not let type checker to pick correct polymorphic version of `map`, `fmap`, `mapM`, `mapM_` or `mapCE`?

Comment: Hungarian notation isn't the general notion of including type information in variable names; it's specifically about *prefixing* type information to the variable name.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There's a little bit of "Hungarian notation", but it's quite different. In short, Haskell's type system removes the need for most of it.

The `map`/`mapM` thing is a neat example. These two functions confer the exact same concept, but cannot be polymorphically represented because abstracting over the difference would be really noisy. So we pick a Hungarian notation instead.

To be clear, the two types are

```
map  ::            (a ->   b) -> ([a] ->   [b])
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> ([a] -> m [b])
```

These look similar, all `mapM` does is add the monad, but not the same. The structure is revealed when you make the following synonyms

```
type Arr    a b = a ->   b
type Klei m a b = a -> m b
```

and rewrite the types as

```
map  ::            Arr    a b -> Arr    [a] [b]
mapM :: Monad m => Klei m a b -> Klei m [a] [b]
```

The thing to note is that `Arr` and `Monad m => Klei m` are often *extremely similar* things. They both form a certain structure known as a "category" which allows us to hoist all kinds of computation inside of it. [0]

What we'd like is to abstract over the choice of category with something like

```
class Mapping cat where
  map :: cat a b -> cat [a] [b]

instance            Mapping (->)     where map = Prelude.map
instance Monad m => Mapping (Klei m) where map = mapM         -- in spirit anyway
```

but it turns out that there is way more to be gained by abstracting over the list part with `Functor` [1]

```
class Functor f where
  map :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)

instance Functor [] where
  map = Prelude.map

instance Functor Maybe where
  map Nothing  = Nothing
  map (Just a) = Just (f a)
```

and so for simplicity's sake, we use Hungarian notation to make the difference of category instead of rolling it up into Haskell's polymorphism functionality.

[0] Notably, the fact that `Klei m` is a category implies `m` is a monad and the category laws become exactly the monad laws. In particular, that's my favorite way for remembering what the monad laws are.

[1] Technically, the sole method of `Functor` is called `fmap` not `map`, but it could and perhaps should have been called just `map`. The `f` was added so that the type signature for `map` remains simple (specialized to lists) and thus is a little less intimidating to beginners. Whether or not that was the right decision is a debate that continues today.

Comment: Nice answer. However, it seems to miss one important point: Why did we pick *Hungarian Notation*? It could have been `Control.Monad.map` as well (OK, maybe except for the name clashes in `base`)

Comment: I suppose you could use Hungarian notation, use module-qualified names, or use polymorphism. Polymorphism is out, especially in early Haskell where trying to mix `Functor`-like and `Category`-like polymorphs would have been nightmarish. Haskell tends to eschew lots of qualified names, so while it wouldn't be a problem to have `Control.Monad.map`, many modules intend to be imported unqualified. So we're left with Hungarian notation.

Comment: I understand that we pick one abstraction from two available. Is it driven by pragmatism or because of a language limitation? Can instances like `Mapping (Klei m)` be defined in Haskell (with extensions)?

Comment: Yep, you could definitely define `Mapping (Klei m)`, but it would require manually annotating which "arrows" are standard versus which are `Klei`sli. You could even define `Functor` atop that as `class Functor cat f where map :: (cat a b) -> (cat (f a) (f b))` but inference will suffer. Edward Kmett's [`hask`](https://github.com/ekmett/hask) project does a lot of this stuff... but don't say I didn't warn you :)

Answer (score 8):

Your assumption is that all of these do roughly the same thing - they don't. `map` and `fmap` are pretty much the same function - `map` is just `fmap` specialized to the `[]` functor (either for historical reasons, or so that beginners would get less confusing type errors - I'm not sure).

`mapM` and `mapM_` on the other hand are like `map` followed by `sequence` or `sequence_` respectively - while what they're doing may look related, they're doing different things. Incidentally, the function that behaves like `fmap` for monads is... `fmap` (which is also aliased with a specialized signature to `liftM`, for historical reasons), as `Monad`s are, by definition, also `Functor`s; note that this is, right now, not enforced by the standard library - a historical oversight that should be corrected with GHC 7.10 if I'm not mistaken.

I don't know what to tell you about `debugM` and `mapCE` as I haven't seen these before.